# Cómo agrego elementos en un comboBox?

Tags: java

use el siguiente código:

```
 comboBox.addItem("IVA Excento");
 comboBox.addItem("Canasta familiar");
 comboBox.addItem("Comun");
```

Pero no me funciona. Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?.

Comment: Agrega más detalles para poderte ayudar. ¿No te muestra nada el combobox? ¿Te da algún tipo de error? ¿Estas utilizando algún IDE o lo estás haciendo a manualmente?

Answer (score 4):

En teoría el `combobox.addItem("texto");` debería de funcionar, a mi me acaba de funcionar, pero si preguntas es porque obviamente algo anda mal, otra forma de llenar un jComboBox podría ser la siguiente:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel modelo_cmb = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
modelo_cmb.addElement("IVA Excento");
modelo_cmb.addElement("Canasta familiar");
modelo_cmb.addElement("Común");
tuJComboBox.setModel(modelo_cmb);
```

a continuación muestro que el código que he escrito me ha funcionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este seria el "error" que me salta:Type safety: The method addItem(Object) belongs to the raw type JComboBox. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized, pero me lo pone como un warining, no como error.

Comment: en este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596020/jcombobox-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-jcomboboxe-should-be-param) hablan sobre tu advertencia, en que IDE estas trabajando? En que parte llenas el jComboBox?

Comment: Estaba poniendolo en el actionPerformed, actualmente lo tengo trabajando: JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
  comboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    
   }
  });
  comboBox1.setBounds(312, 145, 145, 20);
  comboBox1.addItem("Efectivo");
  comboBox1.addItem("Con tarjeta");
  comboBox1.addItem("Con cheque al portador");
  comboBox1.addItem("Con cheque a 30 dias");
  contentPane.add(comboBox1); Gracias por la ayuda!